# Which namespace and assembly should I use to declare a converter in a shared project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Which namespace and assembly should I use to declare a converter in a shared project in Xamarin.

for this ressource

```
 <TabbedPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="widthConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</TabbedPage.Resources>
```

If I choose windowsPhone as Startup Project this declaration work :

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam.WinPhone"
```

If I choose Android as Startup Project this declaration work :

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam.Android"
```

Now what should I use to make it work for MixedPlateform, I tried this but with no success :

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam"
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT there is my full code for a better understanding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="LeMagXam.View.HomePage"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam"
Title="LeMag"
BackgroundImage="bg_light.png"
ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}"
>

<TabbedPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="widthConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</TabbedPage.Resources>


<TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPage Title="{Binding Name}">
<-- ... -->

        <Image Source="{Binding Category.ImageArticleTitle.Source}" HorizontalOptions="Start"
               WidthRequest="{Binding , Converter={StaticResource widthConverter},
                               ConverterParameter=150}"

<-- ... -->
        </ContentPage>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

WidthConverter.cs

```
namespace LeMagXam
{
    public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter implementation

        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double)parameter * App.RatioWidth;
        }

        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. Following.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a **Shared Project** has no compilable outputs.

Therefore there will be no assembly *LeMagXam* that would be generated.

Instead the contents of the **Shared Project** are compiled **into** the project that references it.

Therefore the following, like you mentioned, will both work in their own *platform-specific* projects:-

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam.WinPhone" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXam.Android"
```

To get around this you may be able to just use:-

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam"
```

Should this not work, consider creating a **PCL** project and put the converter within it.

A **PCL Project** has a compilable output.  Hence you would be able to use the **same declaration** across all XAML pages that uses the same output assembly, like so:-

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeMagXam;assembly=LeMagXamPCL"
```

Remember to reference the **PCL Project** from the *platform-specific* project.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what the `.WinPhone` and `.Android` are there for. Remember, the assembly is the name that the class has to reference. `LeMagXam` is likely to contain only the common elements, not the specifics for the platform. Think of `System.Collection` - that namespace doesn't have `List` or `Dictionary` in, but `System.Collection.Generics` does

What does the width converter do? If it simply a property that does some basic maths (say converts feet to meters), then there is no requirement to have this in a platform specific namespace. If it is setting a platform specific width, then again you don't need to use a platform specific namespace as Xam.Forms already allows you to do that sort of thing anyway with the `Device.OnPlatform` (I think it's called) method.

Hope this helps

Comment: My converter is in the same namespace LeMagXam

Comment: This converter is for all platforms not for one specific.
If you want more details this converter take his parameter and multiply with screen ratio for return a width to my image who will display for have the same rendering