# How to obtain the same rendering of image's width in a cross platform app?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to understand the logic of Xamarin with images.

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176868/which-namespace-and-assembly-should-i-use-to-declare-a-converter-in-a-shared-pro) hasn't obtained solution. I am trying to work around the problem and think differently.

I am developing a cross platform app. If I don't want a full-screen image and I specify a width, the rendering will not be the same according to the different screen sizes. What is the best practice to have the same rendering?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

[image: This is what I would like]

This is what I am trying to do

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" RowHeight="150">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="150" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                    <Grid VerticalOptions="End" Padding="0,0,10,15">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Image Source="{Binding Category.ImageArticleTitle.Source}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Aspect="Fill" />
                                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="5,5,0,0">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="20" WidthRequest="320"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: have you tried the px/cm or twips method?

Comment: No actually, I didn't know twips method. I would like to do this in XAML but converters seems to be necessary. And I come back to my previous post: converters in a shared projects

Comment: Try and ask this on the xammy forum instead.

Comment: I already posted my question on Xamarin Forum: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28610/xamarin-and-images

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want and image to be the same size on every platform/phone. But I think the best thing you can do is use a Grid so your image scales the same on every screen. 
That way when you have a small phone screen the image gets smaller and with a big screen the images get bigger according to the screen size. This will make your screen look the same on every platform/phone.